# Spinnaker !ERROR No user named 'my_user/api-kcs-cluster-com:port' exists in your kubeconfig file. when I run 'hal deploy apply' but user is defined?

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, kubeconfig, spinnaker-halyard

Hello I'm currently trying to deploy spinnaker by running halyard container via Docker

Here's my Kubeconfig file: /root/.kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/mycert
    server: https://api.kcs.cluster.com:port
  name: api-kcs-cluster-com:port
contexts:
- context:
    cluster:  api-kcs-cluster-com:port
    namespace: dev
    user: my_user/api-kcs-cluster-com:port
  name: dev/ api-kcs-cluster-com:port/my_user
current-context: dev/api-kcs-cluster-com:port/my_user
kind: Config
preferences: {}
user:
- name: my_user/api-kcs-cluster-com:port
  user:
     token: *******
```

heres my hal config pertaining to kubernetes provider

```
kubernetes:
    enabled: true
    accounts:
    - name: my_user
      requiredGroupMembership: []
      permissions: {}
      dockerRegistries: []
      providerVersion: V2
      configureImagePullSecrets: true
      cacheThreads: 1
      namespaces:
      - dev
      omitNamespaces: []
      kinds: []
      omitKinds: []
      customResources: []
      cachingPolicies: []
      kubeconfigFile: /root/.kube/config
      rawResourcesEndpointConfig:
        kindExpressions: []
        omitKindExpressions: []
      oAuthScopes: []
      onlySpinnakerManaged: false
    primaryAccount: my_user
```

Double checked the kubeconfig file, Looked at the information in the hal config to make sure everything was accurate. Not sure why i get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from `user` -> `users` in your kubeconfig

```
users:
- name: my_user/api-kcs-cluster-com:port
  user:
     token: *******
```

Comment: -facepalm- I had it to users before but I changed due to editing the config file multiple times. Now I'm getting a different error hahaha